# How to fix BindingContextFactory import?

Tags: java, import

my friend send me Chess game to write tests for it, but I can't run it, because this import:

```
import static com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.LOGGER;
```

is not working, I thought it should've been in dependencies, so I can just resolve them, but it's not the case, what should I do?

Comment: Using classes from internal packages, espcially from the `com.sun` namespace is a bad idea. What is `LOGGER` used for?  There are much better logging libraries.

Comment: Just to log info that the game couldn't find the figure on given position. Problem is, we have to have at least 2 uses of `LOGGER`.

Comment: Get rid of it, use a better library.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: try https://www.slf4j.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this